# WebLogic OBIEE Scheduler Component Down

Tags: console, weblogic, redhat, scheduler, obiee

I have an OBIEE 11g installation in a Red Hat machine, but I'm finding problems to make it running. I can start WebLogic and its services, so I’m able to enter the WebLogic console and Enterprise Manager, but problems come when I try to  start OBIEE components with opmnctl command.
The steps I’m performing are the following:

1) Start WebLogic

```
cd /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin/
./startWebLogic.sh
```

2) Start NodeManager

```
cd /home/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/
./startNodeManager.sh
```

3) Start Managed WebLogic

```
cd /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin/
./startManagedWebLogic.sh bi_server1
```

4) Set up OBIEE Components

```
cd /home/Oracle/Middleware/instances/instance1/bin/
./opmnctl startall
```

The result is:

```
opmnctl startall: starting opmn and all managed processes...
================================================================================
opmn id=JustiziaInf.mmmmm.mmmmm.9999
Response: 4 of 5 processes started.

ias-instance id=instance1
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ias-component/process-type/process-set:
  coreapplication_obisch1/OracleBISchedulerComponent/coreapplication_obisch1/

Error
--> Process (index=1,uid=1064189424,pid=4396)
  failed to start a managed process after the maximum retry limit
  Log:
  /home/Oracle/Middleware/instances/instance1/diagnostics/logs/OracleBISchedulerComponent/
coreapplication_obisch1/console~coreapplication_obisch1~1.log
```

5) Check the status of components

```
cd /home/Oracle/Middleware/instances/instance1/bin/
./opmnctl status

Processes in Instance: instance1
---------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
ias-component                    | process-type       |     pid | status  
---------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
coreapplication_obiccs1          | OracleBIClusterCo~ |    8221 | Alive   
coreapplication_obisch1          | OracleBIScheduler~ |     N/A | Down    
coreapplication_obijh1           | OracleBIJavaHostC~ |    8726 | Alive   
coreapplication_obips1           | OracleBIPresentat~ |    6921 | Alive   
coreapplication_obis1            | OracleBIServerCom~ |    7348 | Alive
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the log files from  /home/Oracle/Middleware/instances/instance1/diagnostics/logs/OracleBISchedulerComponent/
coreapplication_obisch1/console~coreapplication_obisch1~1.log.

I would recommend trying the the steps in the below link as this is a common issue when upgrading OBIEE.

http://www.askjohnobiee.com/2012/11/fyi-opmnctl-failed-to-start-managed.html

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, what your log says, but try these below steps and check if it works or not

1. Login as superuser
2. cd $ORACLE_HOME/Apache/Apache/bin
3. chmod 6750 .apachectl
4. logout and login as ORACLE user
5. opmnctl startproc process-type=OracleBIScheduler

Comment: I think that the problem is not Apache. And the statement opmnctl startproc not found.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer; nowhere in the original question does it suggest any kind of permission issues, nor user ids associated with the installation.